# Does anyone have an example of an incoming Twilio Voice Request?

Tags: twilio

I am modifying our old Twilio application, and am trying to wrap some endpoint tests around it. One thing I have not had any luck with on the Twilio site or elsewhere is finding any examples of the incoming POST from Twilio, specifically the format and Content Type.

In our code, I can see that we are looking for both our constants (as query parameters) and Twilio constants (in the body of the message). But since I'm in a test environment, I can't tell if we're receiving form data, x-www-form-urlencoded, xml, or what. We send TwiML responses in XML, but so far I haven't gotten any format of incoming data to work correctly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Webhook requests from Twilio include parameters as form-encoded data.

The list of base parameters for each Voice Request are here:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request

and each SMS Request are here:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request

Depending on what causes the webhook request (eg Status Callback, Recording Callback, Gather) their may be other parameters included.  All of those are documented in the API and TwiML docs.

For real time monitoring of webhook requests, as suggested by Louis, tools like ngrok or requestb.in are good.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've read that documentation over and over - the problem is that I have code, which works, which should accept form-encoded data; and when I try to send what is expected via POSTMAN, it fails. A real-life environment would help me, as you both say, but what would be really sweet is a simple HTTP document which I could test against. I feel like it must be out there, but I'll do all the setup if I need to.

Comment: What error are you getting back?  I'm happy to take a look at your POSTMan config as well.

Comment: It turns out some Jersey filter is eating the request body out from under us. So Postman is working fine for me now, but thank you for all the good info and links!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use ngrok to help you out with this. Get the client, run it and set 
one of your Twilio numbers voice endpoints to point to your ngrok url.

When dialling the number, the request will come through ngrok. When running you can browse to a local url and see all the traffic that has come in and that which has been sent out.

When it is running and after you have set everything up correctly and called the number, you will see the list being populated in your browser. You can then click on an incoming request and find out everything you would like to know about the incoming request.

You can also replay requests, which I have found useful for testing server side logic.

I hope this helps.

https://ngrok.com/